# UIView shadow on Ipad doesn't span the width of the view correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiview

I have created a simple extension on UIView to add a "drop" shadow to UIViews, it works great on iPhone, but does not work correctly on iPad. I can't figure out what I am missing, any ideas on how to improve/fix this so that the shadow shows correctly on both iPad and iPhone would be awesome

```
extension UIView {
func addShadow() {
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
}
```

}

This is what it comes out looking like on iPad:

[image: UIView with shadow on iPad]

I am calling it from a UIView like so:

```
class AggregateDataViewImplementation: UIView, AggregateDataView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        layoutView()
    }

    private func layoutView() {
        self.addShadow()
    }

...
```

}

Comment: when are you calling addShadow? and what is the UIView that's calling it?

Comment: can you please tell that where are you adding the method for shadow

Comment: You are calling addShadow in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: I have updated the question above to show how the method is being called. We are calling it from a UIView after awake from nib

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you problem is here:

```
self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
```

the shadow's rect is according to here, if the self.bounds is not accroding to the actual rect，may have a error show. Suggest that write like this ,

```
 self.bgView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bgView.bounds).cgPath
 self.bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
 self.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
 self.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
 self.bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
```

hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments got me thinking, and I was able to get this working perfectly by moving things around a bit! Thank you to all to took the time to comment!

I kept the extension from UIView, but moved the call from the `awakeFromNib()` call into the `viewDidLoad()` call of the views parent VC. In order to deal with device rotation I added a call to `viewWillTransition(...)` the full snippet is below.

```
 // MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let primaryView = primaryView as? AggregateDataViewImplementation else { return }
    primaryView.didTapClose = { [weak self] in
        self?.didTapClose?()
    }
    primaryView.tableView.delegate = self
    primaryView.tableView.dataSource = self
    primaryView.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "AggregateDataTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    primaryView.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AggregateDataTableViewCell")
    primaryView.addShadow()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let primaryView = primaryView as? AggregateDataViewImplementation else { return }
    primaryView.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
        guard let primaryView = self.primaryView as? AggregateDataViewImplementation else { return }
        primaryView.addShadow()
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

thanks again!